# How to Modify XML using java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two node having same name. i want to modify one particular node value. For example

```
 <names> 
    <name>one</name> 
    <name>two</name>
    <name>three</name> 
    <name>four</name> 
    <name>five</name> 
    </names>
```

In the above example i want to change last node value "five" to new value "six". is this possible in DOM..?? i am new to this concept, please guide me. Thanks for valuable replies.

Comment: Use Google to learn about DOM, and then learn how implement DOM parsing in Java.

Comment: Thank you guys i got answer from google. if anyone having issues like this please refere http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0625.html this will guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of doing exactly what you describe.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/JavaDOMeditLocateaNodeandChangeItsContent.htm

Answer (score 1):

The A-Z of DOM using java: http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In particular, you can reference collections of child objects of 'names' as a NodeList. see [Node.getChildNodes()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29)